# JQuery-Validate Plugin : My form gets submitted when adding rules to input "file"

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-file-upload

I am new to front-end validations, so I was hoping for a little help over here.I am using **JQuery Validate Plugin** to validate my form before submission.
Here is a short sample of my form :

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('employees.store') }}" name="createEmployeeForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName">
  <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName">
  <input type="file" id="employee-image" name="employee_image">
  <button id="submit_btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I added set of rules to my inputs "FirstName and LastName".
When I press on the "Submit" button it validates the form first before submission which is **Good**, however after I add rules and custom validation method to (input of type "file"), the form is submitted to server-side and no previous validations occurs.
Here is my js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
      });
      $("form[name='createEmployeeForm']").validate({
          rules: {
            FirstName: "required",
            LastName: "required",
            employee_image: {
              accept: "jpg,png,jpeg,gif",
              filesize: 1048576
            }
          },
          // Specify validation error messages
          messages: {
            employee_image: {
              accept: "uploaded file should have an image-extension : jpg,png,jpeg,gif and less than 1 MB "
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              form.submit();
            }
          });
      });
```

I tried preventdefault on the submit button and return false in the submit handler, but nothing seems to work out and I don't want to submit my form via ajax.
**Guidance is appreciated**

Comment: Did you make sure to include the additional-methods file too? `accept` method is not part of the core, you also need to include the additional-methods file to get it.
Also, `messages` should not be inside `rules`, it should be on its own. See https://jsfiddle.net/Arkni/yasutt29/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, It works fine now.
I didn't know `accept` exits in the additional-methods file. As for the `messages` being inside `rules` it was a typo when I wrote the snippet.I will update it. Thanks again :) @Arkni

Answer (score 1):

"accept" method is provided as add-on, that's why additional-method file should be included as mentioned in the **Documentation**  :

> Some more methods are provided as add-ons, and are currently included
> in additional-methods.js in the download package. Not all of them are
> documented here:
>
> accept – Makes a file upload accept only specified mime-types.
> creditcard – Makes the element require a credit card number.
> extension – Makes the element require a certain file extension.
> phoneUS – Validate for valid US phone number.
> require_from_group – Ensures a given number of fields in a group are complete.

Reference : [JQuery Validate Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)